# Google Cloud Datastore: Working with Keys

Tags: php, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I haven't found any documentation on this, although it must exist somewhere, being as it's rather simple.

I can query using PHP for all of the tasklists (for example) as follows:

```
$query = $datastore->query();
$query->kind('tasklist')
        ->filter('date_approved', '<', 0)
        ->order("date_approved")
        ->order("date_updated", $query::ORDER_DESCENDING)
        ->limit(50);
$res = $datastore->runQuery($query);
```

And to see the key (for example, for updates), I've been using:

```
foreach($res as $r) {
    $parentkey = $r->key()->pathEnd()['name'];
    echo $parentkey; //"default"
}
```

I noticed if i "JOIN" child records, that were created as follows:

```
$childkey = $datastore->key('tasklist', $parentkey)
                ->pathElement('task', 'task001');
$entity = $datastore->entity($childkey, $myTaskArray);
$datastore->upsert($entity);
```

When I later query for those by "parent" key:

```
$subquery = $datastore->query();
$subquery->kind('task')
    ->filter('date_approved','<',0)
    ->hasAncestor( $datastore->key('tasklist', $parentkey) )
    ->order("date_approved")
    ->order("date_updated", $subquery::ORDER_DESCENDING);
$subres = $datastore->runQuery($subquery);
```

Then printing the key for the child will work the same:

```
foreach($subres as $sr){
    $childkey = $sr->key()->pathEnd()['name'];
    echo $childkey; //"task001"
}
```

Is there a method for working with keys and keys of ancestors that's less goofball than: $entity->key()->pathEnd()['name'];

For example, in MongoDB

```
$myobj = array();
$db->Insert($myobj);
echo (string) $myobj['_id']; //key
```

Also, shouldn't i be able to update a document by providing the key alone, and not having to specify the ancestor key?

```
$childkey = $datastore->key('tasklist', $parentkey)
           ->pathElement('task', "task001");
$entity = $datastore->lookup($childkey);
$entity = $datastore->entity($childkey, $myUpdatedTaskArray);
$datastore->update($entity, array("allowOverwrite"=>true));
```

versus:

```
$childkey = $datastore->key('task', "task001");
$entity = $datastore->lookup($childkey);
$entity = $datastore->entity($childkey, $myUpdatedTaskArray);
$datastore->update($entity, array("allowOverwrite"=>true));
```

Lastly, can i query for entities AND their descendants without having to do a join (as i'm doing above), while still filtering (date_approved<0 for example) and sorting (date_updated DESC also for example).

*NOTE: goofball being a non-technical term*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a method for working with keys and keys of ancestors that's less goofball than: $entity->key()->pathEnd()['name'];

Keys in datastore are a rather complex concept, so they're not able to be used quite in the same way you suggest from your work with Mongo. However, there are some helpers on the `Google\Cloud\Datastore\Key` class which would simplify your code a little bit. You could use `pathEndIdentitifer` in place of `pathEnd()['name']`. For instance, `$key->pathEndIdentifier()`. This is quite useful especially in cases where you may not know whether the key uses an ID or a Name.

> Also, shouldn't i be able to update a document by providing the key alone, and not having to specify the ancestor key?

Unfortunately not. A key of form `[Parent: john, Child: junior]` refers to an entirely different entity than a key of form `[Child: junior]`. To use parent entities, you must supply the full key path. If however you can think of ways to make this easier on you, please let me know, preferably by [filing an issue](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-php/issues). I'd love to figure out how to make this easier -- I know it is a bit complex currently.

> Lastly, can i query for entities AND their descendants without having to do a join (as i'm doing above), while still filtering (date_approved<0 for example) and sorting (date_updated DESC also for example).

Unfortunately not. You can query for either one kind or none (i.e. [a kindless query](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-kindless-query-php)). This latter type can query multiple kinds, but you cannot do filtering on entities properties or values.

Comment: Thank you @jdp -- ALL SOLID answers. And very helpful.